# Flatten dictionary values with list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten

I have python dictionary that contains key and values. Its values are all inside one list. However, other elements might be inside another list. I want to return only 1D flat list irrespectively of the situation.

Example:

```
sample_dict1 = 

defaultdict(list,
            {'File1.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File1.xlsx'],
'File2.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File2.xlsx'],
'File3.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File3.xlsx', ['Path/OLD/Subpath/File3.xlsx']],
'File4.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File4.xlsx', ['Path/OLD/Subpath/File4.xlsx'],
               ['Path/changed/Subpath/File4.xlsx']] } )
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
output = 

defaultdict(list,
            {'File1.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File1.xlsx'],
'File2.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File2.xlsx'],
'File3.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File3.xlsx', 'Path/OLD/Subpath/File3.xlsx'],
'File4.xlsx': ['Path/NEW/Subpath/File4.xlsx', 'Path/OLD/Subpath/File4.xlsx',
               'Path/changed/Subpath/File4.xlsx'] } )
```

my attempt:

```
def flatten(xs):
    for x in xs:
        if isinstance(x, str):
            yield x
        elif isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
            yield from flatten(x)

for k, v in sample_dict1.items():
        sample_dict1[k] = list(flatten(k])
```

From question [Flatten list of lists within dictionary values before processing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785196/flatten-list-of-lists-within-dictionary-values-before-processing-in-pandas)

Comment: Use `sample_dict1[k] = list(flatten(v))`, not `sample_dict1[k] = list(flatten(k))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

1. Use `flatten(v)`instead of `flatten(k)`
2. Get your parentheses right: `list(flatten(v))` ìnstead of `list(flatten(v])`

```py
def flatten(xs):
    for x in xs:
        if isinstance(x, str):
            yield x
        elif isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
            yield from flatten(x)

for k, v in sample_dict1.items():
        sample_dict1[k] = list(flatten(v))
```